# $.getJSON not returning anything despite success

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, echonest

I'm relatively new to the whole jQuery thing, so apologies if this is a really obvious thing.

My basic problem is that the URL within the .getJSON() function is not returning anything despite the JSON file being valid.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var key = '*****************'

  var getMusic = function() {
      $.getJSON('http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/song/search?api_key=' + key + '&artist=led+zeppelin', function(data) {
          $('.songs').append('<li>success</li>');
          data['songs'].forEach(function(d) {
              $('.songs').append('<li>' + d['title'] + '</li>');
          });
      });
  };

  $('.click').click(getMusic);
});
```

So the "success" gets appended to the list, but nothing else does. The debug console in Chrome gives me the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`

I'm assuming this means that the URL is not passing anything to the function. But the URL is valid. If I just type it into Chrome, I get the following response.

```
{  
  "response":{  
  "status":{  
     "version":"4.2",
     "code":0,
     "message":"Success"
  },
  "songs":[  
     {  
        "artist_id":"ARDIBRT1187B9AF176",
        "id":"SOWOYIL14EEE38DB16",
        "artist_name":"Led Zeppelin",
        "title":"St. Tristan's Sword (Rough Mix)"
     },
     {  
        "artist_id":"ARDIBRT1187B9AF176",
        "id":"SOWTZWK12A6D4FC7A8",
        "artist_name":"Led Zeppelin",
        "title":"Rock And Roll - 2007 Remastered Version Live Version From The Song Remains The Same"
     },
     {  
        "artist_id":"ARDIBRT1187B9AF176",
        "id":"SOWYEOY14EEE39630C",
        "artist_name":"Led Zeppelin",
        "title":"Bring It On Home (Rough Mix)"
     },
     {  
        "artist_id":"ARDIBRT1187B9AF176",
        "id":"SOXAPFT12AF72A0776",
        "artist_name":"Led Zeppelin",
        "title":"The Ocean (Live Album Version)"
     },
     {  
        "artist_id":"ARDIBRT1187B9AF176",
        "id":"SOTYJLS12A8C13B4A9",
        "artist_name":"Led Zeppelin",
        "title":"Somethin' Else - \"Tasty Pop Sundae\" Live Version From BBC Sessions"
     },
     {  
        "artist_id":"ARDIBRT1187B9AF176",
        "id":"SOUQMIU12B0B8083DF",
        "artist_name":"Led Zeppelin",
        "title":"1-06 For Your Life"
     },
     {  
        "artist_id":"ARDIBRT1187B9AF176",
        "id":"SOUKOUX12B0B80B0BA",
        "artist_name":"Led Zeppelin",
        "title":"308 - The Song Remains The Same"
     },
     {  
        "artist_id":"ARDIBRT1187B9AF176",
        "id":"SOXXFOR12A8C13A5C6",
        "artist_name":"Led Zeppelin",
        "title":"Whole Lotta Love - \"Top Gear\" Live Version From BBC Sessions"
     },
     {  
        "artist_id":"ARDIBRT1187B9AF176",
        "id":"SOXHHNN14DB525B914",
        "artist_name":"Led Zeppelin",
        "title":"Heartbreaker (For Voice)"
     },
     {  
        "artist_id":"ARDIBRT1187B9AF176",
        "id":"SOXWXGG12B0B80B0AF",
        "artist_name":"Led Zeppelin",
        "title":"1-07 Trampled Underfoot"
     },
     {  
        "artist_id":"ARDIBRT1187B9AF176",
        "id":"SOXWUUS12B0B80B0D9",
        "artist_name":"Led Zeppelin",
        "title":"412 - Moby Dick -- Bonzo's Montreux"
     },
     {  
        "artist_id":"ARDIBRT1187B9AF176",
        "id":"SOXVXFK12B0B80B0C2",
        "artist_name":"Led Zeppelin",
        "title":"02 Going to California"
     },
     {  
        "artist_id":"ARDIBRT1187B9AF176",
        "id":"SOXZGKC12A8C13B4C9",
        "artist_name":"Led Zeppelin",
        "title":"Heartbreaker - \"In Concert\" Live Version From BBC Sessions"
     },
     {  
        "artist_id":"ARDIBRT1187B9AF176",
        "id":"SOXEDBF14EC9C340F9",
        "artist_name":"Led Zeppelin",
        "title":"10 Ribs & All/Carrot Pod Pod (Pod) (Reference Mix)"
     },
     {  
        "artist_id":"ARDIBRT1187B9AF176",
        "id":"SOYIZYO12C106D04DB",
        "artist_name":"Led Zeppelin",
        "title":"Ramble On (1999 Star System Mix)"
     }
    ]
   }
  }
```

I'm not sure why the code isn't performing as expected.

Comment: And you opened the console and checked for errors, right ?

Comment: Have you tried dropping `console.log(data)` into the callback to see what's really returned? You should also be able to see that in the browser console (the Network tab, depending on your browser).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing wrongly the data from `$.getJSON`
You need to get **response** first:

**data.response['songs']**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var key = '*****************'

  var getMusic = function() {
      $.getJSON('http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/song/search?api_key=' + key + '&artist=led+zeppelin', function(data) {
          $('.songs').append('<li>success</li>');
          data.response['songs'].forEach(function(d) {
              $('.songs').append('<li>' + d['title'] + '</li>');
          });
      });
  };

  $('.click').click(getMusic);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `data` is the root JSON object, which has a `response` property. `songs` is in the `response` property, so in order to access it, you have to access `data.response.songs`

The correct code would be:

```
data.response.songs.forEach(function (song) {
    $('.songs').append('<li>' + song.title + '</li>');
});
```

---

## If you must use JSONP

According to @Pointy's comment, it seems that you should use [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) due to security reasons (possibly because of cross domain issues).

In order to use JSONP, you must provide a callback function appending `&callback=?` to the end of your service endpoint. (jQuery will send the appropiate `callback` value when sendng the request)

```
// Note the trailing "callback=?"
$.getJSON('http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/song/search?api_key=' + key + '&artist=led+zeppelin&callback=?')
.done(function (data) {
    $('.songs').append('<li>success</li>');
    data.response.songs.forEach(function (song) {
        $('.songs').append('<li>' + song.title + '</li>');
    });
});
```

Comment: You're right about the structure of the response, but based on some documentation at the Echonest site I think the OP will have to switch to JSONP in order to use the service directly from a browser.